# How to extend callback QRL in child component in Qwik JS?

Tags: qwik, qwikjs

In Qwik JS I am trying to create a modal that closes when <kbd>Esc</kbd> is pressed. The modal needs to be accessible from anywhere, so I put it in layout.tsx.

**layout.tsx**

```typescript
import {component$, Slot, useStore} from '@builder.io/qwik';
import Header from '../components/header/header';
import Modal from '~/components/modal/modal';

export default component$(() => {
  const store = useStore({
    showModal: true,
  });

  return (
    <>
      <main>
        <Header/>
        <section>
          <Slot/>
        </section>
        <button onclick$={() => store.showModal = true}>Show modal</button>
      </main>
      {
        store.showModal
        && (
          <Modal onClose={$(() => {
            store.showModal = false;
          })}>
            foo
          </Modal>
        )
      }
    </>
  );
});
```

I want to close the modal *only* when <kbd>Esc</kbd> is pressed, so the "keyup" callback first checks if <kbd>Esc</kbd> was pressed, then resolves the passed QRL, and then executes it.

**modal.tsx**

```typescript
import {component$, QRL, Slot, useVisibleTask$} from '@builder.io/qwik';

export type Props = {
  onClose: QRL<() => void>;
}

export default component$((props: Props) => {
  useVisibleTask$(() => {
    const onKeyUp = async (e: KeyboardEvent) => {
      const key = (e as KeyboardEvent).key || (e as KeyboardEvent).code;
      if (key === 'Escape') {
        const cb = await props.onClose.resolve();
        cb();
      }
    };

    document.addEventListener('keyup', onKeyUp, true);

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener('keyup', onKeyUp, true);
    };
  }, {
    strategy: 'document-ready',
  });

  return (
    <div class="modal-bg">
      <div class="modal">
        <Slot/>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
});
```

However, this results in an error:

> Error: Code(14): Invoking 'use*()' method outside of invocation context.

How do I get around this problem? How do I execute more than just the QRL callback that is passed?

Answer (score 2):

The best I found so far is a workaround (or who knows, perhaps this is actually a proper way to do it).

I solved it / worked around it by using a [context](https://qwik.builder.io/docs/components/context/).

### layout.tsx

```typescript
import {component$, createContextId, Slot, useContextProvider, useStore} from '@builder.io/qwik';
import Header from '../components/header/header';
import Modal from '~/components/modal/modal';

export type ShowModalContextData = {
  showModal: boolean;
};

export const ShowModalContextId = 'my.context';
export const ShowModalContext = createContextId<ShowModalContextData>(ShowModalContextId);

export default component$(() => {
  const store = useStore<ShowModalContextData>({
    showModal: true,
  });

  useContextProvider(ShowModalContext, store);

  return (
    <>
      <main>
        <Header/>
        <section>
          <Slot/>
        </section>
        <button onclick$={() => store.showModal = true}>Foo</button>
      </main>
      {
        store.showModal
        && (
          <Modal>
            foo
          </Modal>
        )
      }
    </>
  );
});
```

### modal.tsx

```typescript
import {component$, Slot, useContext, useVisibleTask$} from '@builder.io/qwik';
import {ShowModalContext} from '~/routes/layout';

export default component$(() => {
  const showModalCtx = useContext(ShowModalContext);

  useVisibleTask$(() => {
    const onKeyUp = async (e: KeyboardEvent) => {
      const key = (e as KeyboardEvent).key || (e as KeyboardEvent).code;
      if (key === 'Escape') {
        showModalCtx.showModal = false;
      }
    };

    document.addEventListener('keyup', onKeyUp, true);

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener('keyup', onKeyUp, true);
    };
  }, {
    strategy: 'document-ready',
  });

  return (
    <div class="modal-bg">
      <div class="modal">
        <Slot/>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
});
```

This completely removes the need of having to pass a callback down to the child component.

### `document.addEventListener()` vs `useOnDocument()`

Why did I use `document.addEventListener()` in `useVisibleTask$()`, and not `useOnDocument()`, as the docs [suggest](https://qwik.builder.io/docs/cheat/best-practices/)?

I tried that, but as soon as the modal was closed and reopened, the listeners were gone, making it impossible to close the modal.